# JAVA error cannot find a symbol

Tags: java

I need to create a `JAVA` method: `public static int[] Numb()` that reads and returns a series of positive integer values. If the user enters `-1` we should stop accepting values, and then I want to call it in the main method. And we should return to the user integers that he entered them, with the total number.

So if he entered the following:

```
5  6  1  2  3  -1
```

So the total number is : 6
The numbers entered are: `5  6  1  2  3  -1`

I tried the following:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
    }

    public static int[] readNumbers(int[] n)
    {
        int[] a = new int[n.length];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0;i<n.length;i++) {
            String token = scan.next();
            a[i] = Integer.nextString();
        }
    }
}
```

[And here is a fiddle of them](http://ideone.com/6bv9rZ). I have an error that said:

> Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
>             a[i] = Integer.nextString();

I am solving this exercise step by step, and I am creating the method that reads integers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why are you passing `int[] n` to `readNumbers` ?

Comment: just to start typing something and start with, a `launcher` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();
    initializeList(numList);
    System.out.println("Num of integer in list: "+numList.size());
 }
 public static void initializeList(List<Integer> numList) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag) {
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        if(num==-1) {
           flag = false;
        }else {
           numList.add(num);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
 }
```

Since the number of integers is unknown, use ArrayList. It's size can be altered unlike arrays. 
You can create something like arraylist on your own..it can be done like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    CustomArray c = new CustomArray(3);
    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag) {
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        if (num == -1) {
           flag = false;
        } else {
           c.insert(num);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.numList));
    }
    sc.close();
    }

}

class CustomArray {
    int[] numList;
    int size; // size of numList[]
    int numOfElements; // integers present in  numList[]

    public CustomArray(int size) {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       numList = new int[size];
       this.size = size;
       numOfElements = 0;
    }

    void insert(int num) {
    if (numOfElements < size) {
        numList[numOfElements++] = num;
    } else {
        // list is full
        size = size * 2; //double the size, you can use some other factor as well
        //create a new list with new size
        int[] newList = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
           //copy all the elements in new list
           newList[i] = numList[i];
        }

        numList = newList;//make numList equal to new list
        numList[numOfElements++] = num;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, we've been told not to use Lists, we should resolve it using normal arrays, but thanks by the way, it might helps me.

Comment: So are you asked to create something like ArrayLists on your own using normal arrays?

Comment: We didn't take, Lists, so I think we can't use it to solve this, if it is impossible, I will take your answer and work on it.

Comment: check the edited answer. I think something like this should help you.

Answer (score 6):

`Integer.nextString()` doesn't exist, to get the next entered integer value, you may change your loop to either :

```
for(int i = 0;i<n.length;i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
```

or as @vikingsteve suggested :

```
for(int i = 0;i<n.length;i++) {
            String token = scan.next();
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(token);
        }
```

Comment: sir, how to change this code, so he may accept variable length of array, and my method should not take a parameter, it should be like `int[] readNumbers()` not `int[] readNumbers(int[] a)`

Comment: The user should enter an array that I don't know his length so I can't tell him `Please enter the array length` I should scan all his inputs until he enter `-1`

Comment: @androidnation make use of a `List`, or create a method that does return the original array.length + 1 with all values copied and the new value at index length-1